# Where to put files?

Tags: linux-mint, gcc

I downloaded a pre-built cross-compiler, and it had no Makefile, Readme, instructions, or anything. However, it came from a reputable resource, so its not malware or anything (it came from OS-Dev-wiki). Below was the file structure it came zipped up with:


./cross-compiler-folder-name

  ./usr

./usr/bin/

./usr/include/


And a few other folders that match some found inside the /usr directory on the computer. So, to install this compiler, my guess is that I copy the files in the downloaded folder to the folders indicated on the computer?

So, for example, I copy the contents of "./cross-compiler-folder-name/usr/bin" to "/usr/bin" on the computer?

Also, the computer is Linux Mint, so I can copy files to places like /usr/bin without a problem, so don't tell me how to do that.


Thanks in advance!!


**Edit:**

[This is the link it came from.](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler%23Prebuilt_Toolchains)
The particular file was a tar.xz file, if thats any help. The file is called "i686-elf 4.9.1 target".

Comment: Could you give us the link to where it came from? I would *guess* it's supposed to go in /usr/local, managed by something like GNU stow. Or maybe it's actually a package of some sort, intended for a .tgz-based package manager... But anyway, copying random files into /usr/bin (etc.) is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Okay, I posted it in the question.

Comment: Copying it globally probably isn't a good idea. Just use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and friends as-needed.